# Proving convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {a^{x(n)}}$, $a\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How in general do we prove the convergence (or divergence) of: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {a^{x(n)}}$ such that $a\in \mathbb R$ and $x(n)$ is function of $n$, for example, $a=e, x=\sqrt n$?

The trick they use [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) for $\frac 1 {2^n}$ can't be used with transcendentals for example like in my example above.

**Note:** no integrals, nor Taylor, nor Zeta.

Comment: You need the index n to appear in the term expression.

Comment: I want it to be as general as possible, not just for $a^n$ or $a^{\sqrt n}$, is there another way to represent that? @Paul

Comment: @GinKin you can write $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^{x(n)}}$, where $x$ is a function of $n$.

Comment: Is $x$ strictly increasing?

Comment: @sranthrop if $x$ isn't increasing then the series must be diverging no?

Comment: I think that if $x(n)=\ln n$, it diverges. Not sure. EDIT: It diverges if $a<e$.

Comment: If it's too broad then let's keep $x$ to polynomials only (linear, inverse, power and root functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only a partial answer!**

> Let $a>1$. The series converges, if there is some $b>1$ such that $x(n)\geq\frac{b\log n}{\log a}$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$. The series, however, diverges, if $x(n)\leq\frac{\log n}{\log a}$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$.

*Proof.* If $x(n)\geq\frac{b\log n}{\log a}$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{a^{x(n)}}\leq\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^b}
\end{align*}
for some $N$, and this general harmonic series converges, since $b>1$.

If $x(n)\leq\frac{\log n}{\log a}$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{a^{x(n)}}\geq\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n},
\end{align*}
for some $N$, which diverges.

$\underline{\text{Example:}}$ The series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
converges, since $\sqrt{n}\geq 2\log n$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$.

> If $0<a\leq 1$ and $x(n)\geq0$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb N$, then the series diverges.

*Proof.* We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{a^{x(n)}}\geq\sum_{n=N}^\infty1=\infty,
\end{align*}
which shows divergence.

Comment: What does 'for allmost all' mean in this context? Do you perhaps mean 'for $n$ sufficiently large'?

Comment: Yes. I have learned this phrase in my calculus lecture... but I also know that this phrase is often used in probability/measure theory.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what are the expressions $\frac{\log n}{\log a}$, $\frac{b\log n}{\log a}$ or how you got to them?

Comment: I just wanted to estimate your series by known series. For example I wanted something like $\frac{1}{a^{x(n)}}\leq\frac{1}{n^b}$ to use the comparison test. Solving this with respect to $x(n)$, you get that $x(n)\geq\frac{b\log n}{\log a}$. Here, $\log$ is the logarithm with base $e$, so $\log=\ln$.